# Order Taylor series prediction

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question, taylor-expansion

> **It is easy to add the Taylor expansion, less easy to multiply and even less easy to compose. That said, the main problem lies not in the calculation itself in the prediction orders that need to be expanded in the quantities present in the remarks,**

- I'm interested in more ways of how to predict orders that need to be expanded

**Let's see this through an example :**

Suppose we are asked to find the Taylor polynomial of degree $7$ for $$\fbox{$  e^{x}\sin(x^{2})$}$$
note that 
\begin{align}
e^{x}&\underset{x\to 0}=1+\ldots+o(x^{m})\\
\sin(u)&\underset{x\to 0}=u+\ldots+o(u^{n})\\
\sin(u^2)&\underset{x\to 0}=u^2+\ldots+o(u^{2n})
\end{align}
then:
\begin{align}
e^{x}\sin(x^2)&\underset{x\to 0}=\left(1+\ldots+o(x^{m}) \right)\left(x^{2}+\ldots+o(x^{2n}) \right)\\
&\underset{x\to 0}=x^{2}\underbrace{\left(1+\ldots+o(x^{m}) \right)\left(x^{2}+\ldots+o(x^{2n}) \right)}_{\text{ note this } f(x)}
\end{align}

We have to expand $f(x)$ to order $5$ and best is to choose $m=5$ and $n=4$

- This is an example how to find $m$ and $n$ but I'm interested in more ways